# Accessing javascript variable in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to render a page using puppeteer, extract the name of a dynamic javascript variable on the page, and return the variable as an object. I'm using puppeteer and node.js to do this.

I'm able to get the name of the javascript variable that is being generated on page but anytime I try to print it out to the console I am getting a "**undefined**" error. I've spent the better part of the morning trying to figure this out but I'm stumped. Here's the code below.

```
const puppeteer= require('puppeteer');

var url = 'https://www.website.com';
async function run () {

try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const flashVariableName = await page.evaluate( () => {
        var start = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('var flashvariable_') + 'var '.length;
        var tempDoc = document.documentElement.innerHTML.substr(start);
        var end = tempDoc.indexOf(' =');
        return  tempDoc.substr(0, end);
    });

        console.log(await page.evaluate( (flashVariableName) => flashVariableName ));

        await browser.close();
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Error Occurred", e)
    }
}

run();
```

[image: Console Output]

flashVariableName is returning the right name for the javascript variable on the page but how can I actually get access to the varialble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two issues.

This is the first one:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate( (flashVariableName) => flashVariableName ));
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                |
//                                +--> this is undefined
```

If you look at the documentation for [Page#evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

[image]

What you're missing is the `...args` bit which supplies parameters to the `pageFunction`. It should have been this instead:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate( (flashVariableName) => flashVariableName, flashVariableName ));
//                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But that is not enough because `flashVariableName` is just a string at this point. It is the name of a variable but not the variable itself. You still need to "evaluate" it:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate( (varName) => window[varName], flashVariableName ));
```

However that only works if the variable you are trying to read is available in the global scope (i.e. `window` in your case) **AND** it can be serialised (e.g. if it refers to a function or a DOM element that won't be possible)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code you provided worked as the javascript variable is part of the DOM. I haven't used puppeteer before so I was a bit confused. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `page.evaluate()` method must be serializable. Other ways it will return undefined. Right now you are just returning a `String`. You can see the definition here https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args

```
let theVariableName = tempDoc.substr(0,end);
return {theVariable: theVariableName}
```

After this you can access your variable in your `flashVariableName` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the best easy way. See the bellow example

```
console.log(await page.evaluate("variableName"));
```

with variableName is the variable name in the script.

Comment: thank you, this works like a charm! just to make more awareness, __platform_data__ is the variable name in the script.

Comment: Yep. I think that's simplest way. I'm edited for  answer more clear

Answer (score 0):

If your variable described in page script as global (using var, not let) - "await page.evaluate("variableName")" is working, as written above (thanks to John Martin).
But if you use script with type="module" is does not work (because of module).
For testing goals I found a workaround - put code below to your page code (version for testing, not for production!):

```
<script type="module">
    // you code:
    // import {XXX} from 'YYY.js'
    let var1 = "value1"
    let object2 = { "attrib": "xxx", "fn": (param1, param2) => { return param1 + param2}}
    function func3(param1, param2) { return param1 * param2 }
    
    // Additional method for testing
    // method to return variable value or call function and return result
    window.testcall = (paramName) => {
        // Если запрошенная переменная есть - возвращаем её значение
        try {
            const result = eval(paramName)
            return (typeof result === "object") ? JSON.stringify(result) : result
        } catch( err ) {
            return `error, ${err}`
        }
    }
</script>
```

And now you can get any variable value, call any function or object method inside of page - from console :

```
testcall('var1')
// -> value1
testcall('object2.fn(2, 3)')
// -> 5
testcall('func3(2, 3)')
// -> 6
```

or from puppeteer:

```
page.evaluate("testcall('var1')")
// -> value1
page.evaluate("testcall('object2')")
// -> {"attrib": "xxx"}
page.evaluate("testcall('object2.fn(2, 3)')")
// -> 5
page.evaluate("testcall('func3(2, 3)')")
// -> 6
```

Or you can return object "as is", simplify the code:

```
...
return eval(paramName)      
...
```